# Dynamicly set the datasource in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbset

I am using EF6 and I have 2 different versions of databases (MsSQL).
1 version has a table Person and the other one has not.
I am overriding the`OnModelCreating` and I use the `modelBuilder.Ignore<Person>();`
This works for calling the database for other tables. 
What I would like to accomplish is when I call the entity over EF is  that it returns a new instance of the class Person instead of trying to connect to the DB and get its data.

eg:

```
using(MyEntity ent = new MyEntity("connectionString")
{
  var myPerson = ent.Person.FirstOrDefault(); ==> Depending on version, return the DBData or new Person()
}
```

Comment: That's a versioning problem, not a datasource issue. You already set the datasource dynamically in the code you provided. Why do you want to return some random object instead of performing eg a migration to create the new table? Perhaps what you need is a *different context* for different versions?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: The DB has 2300+ tables and I don't want to create a different context for each one of the version (10+ versions). Also the DB's are in MsSql and MySQL, I know the question is about MsSql but I have to take this into consideration. Besides when I create a different context, what happens to the call to the Person entity? eg: if Person does not excist in the DB ent.Person.FirstOrDefault throws an error

Comment: Do you have any navigation properties referring to `Person`? That would make this very hard.

Comment: @GertArnold At the moment no. It is a flat model DB and I use automapper to create a logical model away from my repository. So they repo is just dumb data retrieval.

Comment: It seems to me that the decision (i.e. some boolean value) whether or not to map `Person` can also be used to return the `DbSet` or a fake `IQueryable` from the context.

Comment: @GertArnold: yes but I don't know how! Another thing is I don't want to clutter my code with if(version < ...), because then we would have to do this for each reference to the Person object and mistakes are easely made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you can add a boolean parameter to your context's constructor:

```
public MyEntity(string connectionString, bool includePerson)
{
    _includePersion = includePerson;
}
```

Now the context can have a property `Person`, or preferably the plural form `People`:

```
public IQueryable<Person> People
{
    get => _includePerson 
        ? Set<Person>()
        : (new[] { new Person() }).AsQueryable();
}
```

*Technically* you should be out of the woods now, because there are no navigation properties to/from `Person`. However, I'm afraid this construct may have more consequences downstream than can be anticipated at first glance. I would make every effort to avoid it. Adding an empty `Person` table to the databases without it would be much better. This could even be done by the application itself, provided that the logged-on database user has the required DDL permissions.

Comment: @GertArnould:  This was exactly what I was looking for. I know that this has lots of consequences, but I cannot add the empty tables to the Db's and I don't see any other alternatives for my problem